# In react native how to add/remove/update menus in DrawerLayoutAndroid?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have created a drawer in my index page so that it loads on application start. Now on logout and login I want to update the menus in drawer. Is there any way to do?

```
<DrawerLayoutAndroid
    drawerWidth={300}
    drawerPosition={DrawerLayoutAndroid.positions.Left}
    renderNavigationView={() => {
        if (drawer && navigator) {
            return navView;
        }
        return null;
    }}
    ref={(drawer) => { !this.state.drawer ? this.setDrawer(drawer) : null }}
>
    {drawer &&
    <Navigator
        initialRoute={Navigate.getInitialRoute()}
        navigationBar={<Toolbar onIconPress={drawer.openDrawer} />}
        configureScene={() => {
                return Navigator.SceneConfigs.FadeAndroid;
            }}
        ref={(navigator) => { !this.state.navigator ? this.setNavigator(navigator) : null }}
        renderScene={(route) => {
            if (this.state.navigator && route.component) {
                return (
                    <View
                        style={styles.scene}
                        showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}>
                        <route.component title={route.title} path={route.path} {...route.props} />
                    </View>
                );
            }
        }}
    />
    }
</DrawerLayoutAndroid>
```